# How to add CBinding in Monodevelop under GNU/Linux?

Tags: monodevelop

The supported languages are F#, C#, VB.NET.

How to add C/C++ binding?

What's the value of URL below?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/mhutch/cbinding

Comment: @LexLi: can you explain how to install? The link you gave has no binary, no how-to.

Comment: If you read through the existing issues there, you know it has been long abandoned. If you want to revive it, you have to learn how to develop/debug an extension on your own. Easier than from scratch, but still out of capability of most people out there. BTW, MonoDevelop is dead, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b So spending any more time on it is not recommended.